# Adding items to Symfony2 parameters array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, parameters, yaml

I have a Symfony2 (2.8.1) application made of many bundles.
I would like to have an 'about' page showing version of each bundle.
To do so I am trying to use a parameters array like this:

```
revision:
  'bundle1':
    version: 1.0.0
    build: 42
  'bundle2':
    version: 1.2.0
    build: 4242
```

and so on.
If I put everything in a single YAML file it works.
Instead I would like to have each bundle defining its revision. Something like:
parameters file of bundle1:

```
revision:
  'bundle1':
    version: 1.0.0
    build: 42
```

and parameters file of bundle2:

```
revision:
  'bundle2':
    version: 1.2.0
    build: 4242
```

If I do this way, the revision array is populated only with values of the last included yaml file.
Is there a way to 'add' entries to a parameter array defined in different yaml files?
BR
  Stefano

Answer (score 0):

I changed approach and solved the problem.
Instead of adding revision information to configuration, I simply create a Yaml file in the config folder of each bundle.
Then I load yaml files contents in an array to be used in the about page.

code is something like:

```
    # first place to check is app config folder
    $kernel_root=$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
    $toLocate[]=$kernel_root.'/config';

    # then get config folder for each active bundle
    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
    $configDirectories=$this->getParameter('kernel.bundles');
    foreach ($configDirectories as $bundleName => $configDirectory) {
        $toLocate[]= $kernel->locateResource('@'.$bundleName).'Resources/config';
    }

    # now get array of revision files
    $locator = new FileLocator($toLocate);
    $yamlRevFiles = $locator->locate('revision.yml', null, false);

    # and finally create array of date read from revision files
    $revs=array();
    foreach ($yamlRevFiles as $yamlRevFile) {
        $revs[]=Yaml::parse($yamlRevFile);
    }
```